# Alter Matching code to run on different shaped data then originally written for

Tags: excel, fuzzy-comparison, vba

I do not recall where I found this code so I cannot give a proper attribution to its author but it `fuzzy matches` two columns of strings

I want to alter the code so that the `LookWith` column is in coluwn `B` not column `E` I have tried for sometime to do this but cannot get this to work without breaking the code

Thanks

The Original shape of the data the code is written for
[image: Original shape of data]

```
Sub FuzzyMatch()
Dim F As Range, n As Long, c As Long, k As Long 'Taisir
Dim FN As String, SN As String, Z, s As Long, r As Long

For r = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
SN = Replace(Cells(r, 1), ",", ""): Z = Split(SN): SN = Z(0)
Set F = Range("E:E").Find(SN)
If Not F Is Nothing Then
  s = F.Row: FN = Cells(s, 5): c = 1
  For n = 1 To UBound(Z): SN = Z(n)
   If Len(SN) < 3 Then GoTo GetNextn
     Set F = Rows(s).Find(SN)
      If Not F Is Nothing Then
       c = c + 1
         If c >= UBound(Z) - 1 Then
           If Cells(s, 6) <> "" Then k = k + 1 Else k = 6
             Cells(s, k).Resize(1, 2).Value = Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value: End If
         GoTo GetNext: End If
GetNextn: Next n: End If
GetNext: Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set F = Range("B:B").Find(SN)`

Comment: I tried that and I am sure it is part of the solution by itself  alters what is matched